# Discover a pattern in a set of spectrograms given a real rating

Tags: time-series, neural-networks, pattern-recognition, spectral-analysis, sequential-pattern-mining

I'm trying to find patterns in a sorted set of spectrograms, each with a rating. The main idea is to train the CNN in such a way that it understands how the pattern "evolves" at each step, taking into account changes in the rating (try to find changes proportional to the rating).

I do not fully understand whether such an approach is possible, given that the pattern is not necessarily located locally on the spectrogram and, in fact, can take any form. At the same time, different patterns most likely exist for a different number of steps.

The only approach that I found is to use a 3D convolution with a batch of spectrograms. However, then it is not clear what the output values ​​should be. Is it possible to reduce the problem to seq2seq and predict a series of ratings? Or is it better to switch to unsupervised approaches?

Comment: Please make clear what your question is. What do you mean by "changes proportional to the rating"?

Comment: @frank My question is how such tasks can be solved in general. Updated the question: I meant "changes proportional to the change in the rating". Since the patterns I'm looking for are arbitrary, I would like to train the network to understand in which way the picture has changed, and take into account not only the subsequent image, but multiple next steps. In this case, the specific change metric is unknown: it can be a change in the position of a part of the spectrogram and a change in the brightness of this part or something else.

Comment: Please add some more information,this is still ery general. And please, add new info as an edit to the post, not only incomments!